# View is behind the extended navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

In the `viewDidLoad` of the root view controller of the `UINavigationController` I add the subview to `navigationBar` and update its frame. Note that the new frame has a **longer height** than that of the original frame.
The problem is that the top of the subview in `view` of root view controller is hidden behind the "extended" nav bar even though, in the storyboard, the constraint of the subview is set to `vertical spacing to top layout guide`. If I remove my subview from from nav bar, the problem disappears.
So, question:

1. Is it considered normal to add subview to the default nav bar provided by navigation controller?
2. When is the best time to add subview and update the frame of nav bar?
3. How can I resolve the issue where part of the view is hidden behind the nav bar with my sub view in it?

Code snippet:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Tile"
    if let frame = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame {

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - 25, width: 25, height: 25))
        label.text = "1234"

        navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(origin: frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height + 25))
        navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Comment: "I add the subview to navigationBar" Well, don't. If you have something to put into the navigation bar, use the view controller's `navigationItem`. If the idea is to give the navigation bar a background, set its `backgroundImage`. But you have no business putting a subview of your own directly into a navigation bar.

Comment: Alright. Basically the reason i want to put subview in it is that when the navigation controller pushes the new controller, that subview in nav bar is still visible, as it is part of nav bar not any presented controller.
In other words, I want a view at the top (just below nav bar) that will slide with pushViewController. That view must be visible regardless of the view of any controller that is visible at a given time. That view is actually a kind of a banner to remind user that anything you do within this nav controller is part of the entire process.

Comment: Then make this view a subview of the navigation controller's view and put it in _front_ of the navigation bar. But what you are trying to do is basically unsupported no matter how you slice it. I would suggest instead that you take a long hard look at why you think you need such a "banner to remind user". There are much better ways to unify your interface. You could use nav bar color as a cue, for example.